# Can't exit do while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop, do-while

I'm building a simple Rock, Paper, Scissors that I can play via a browser console. Using a do/while loop, I'm prompting to select one of three acceptable options "rock", "paper" or "scissors". As soon as the player inputs one of these 3 acceptable options, the do/while loop should terminate. The problem is that it doesn't.

```
function playerPlay(){
    let choice;
    do{
      choice = prompt("Rock, paper or scissors?").toLowerCase();
      console.log(choice);
      console.log(choice !== "rock" || choice !== "paper" || choice !== "scissors");
      console.log(choice === "rock" || choice === "paper" || choice === "scissors");
    } while (choice !== "rock" || choice !== "paper" || choice !== "scissors");
    return choice; 
  }

  playerPlay();
```

I've been trying to debug with console.log and find it mind-boggling that the prompted choice given by the player seems to be working fine (see screen shot below) and that:

1. When input is "rock", "paper" or "scissors", the two console.log boolean tests log "true". The first console.log should log false (unexpected) while the second should log true (expected).
2. When input is "notRockPaperScissors", the first console.log boolean test logs true (expected) while the second console.log boolean test logs false (expected).

[image]

I'm certainly missing the obvious, but as a beginner, I just can't see what's causing this to happen and understanding the cause would definitely help me (and likely other learners). Thanks for helping!

Comment: There is no input you can provide that satisfies the exit condition. If `choice` is `"rock"` then it will not be `"paper"` or `"scissors"` and so the `OR` passes. You want `&&` instead - you want to repeat the loop while the choice is none of them. Or `while( ["rock","paper","scissors"].indexOf(choice) < 0)` if you want to get "fancy".

Comment: using the newer method [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes), e.g. `!["rock","paper","scissors"].includes(choice)`, instead of `.indexOf(choice) < 0` is a little bit cleaner to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `&&` operator instead of the `||` operator.

i.e. instead of this

```
while (choice !== "rock" || choice !== "paper" || choice !== "scissors");
```

Use this

```
while (choice !== "rock" && choice !== "paper" && choice !== "scissors");
```

The reason for this is that we want the program to exit if `choice` takes any of the values [`rock`, `paper`, `scissors`]. and in the `||` operator if anyone of the conditions evaluates true the loop will continue and in `&&` operator if any of the condition evaluates to false the loop will exit. So, if choice takes any of the listed value, the condition will evaluate to false and then the whole condition will evaluate to false.

Answer (score 0):

```js
while (choice !== "rock" || choice !== "paper" || choice !== "scissors")
```

Your condition is always true because the value is not rock or not paper or not sciccors since it can't be all of them. Check with && instead of ||.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the while condition, your program will stack on the while loop until he gets a false condition.

```
while (choice !== "rock" || choice !== "paper" || choice !== "scissors")
```

With the || (OR) logical operator, you'll stack in the infinite loop.
What you need to do is to change to && (AND) operator like this one:

```
while (choice !== "rock" && choice !== "paper" && choice !== "scissors")
```